# Will Tesseract work on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, tesseract

Has any tried tess4j http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/ on Google App Engine with success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tess4j is just a JNI wrapper around a native tesseract library. Native libraries can not be used on GAE, so this will not work.